# add subscription to plesk control panel

Tags: plesk

i add a plesk subscription with the following xml code, this add subscription without any hosting type. i want the hosting type be "website". please help me

```
<packet>
<webspace>
<add>
   <gen_setup>
      <name>ggg.com</name>
      <owner-login>mmm</owner-login>
      <ip_address>111.111.111.111</ip_address>
      <status>0</status>
   </gen_setup>   
   <plan-name>1m</plan-name>
</add>
</webspace>
</packet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct code is:

```
<packet>
<webspace>
<add>
  <gen_setup>
    <name>{domainName}</name>
    <owner-login>{username}</owner-login>
    <ip_address>111.111.111.111</ip_address>
  </gen_setup>
  <hosting>
    <vrt_hst>
      <property>
        <name>ftp_login</name>
        <value>ftp_{username}</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>ftp_password</name>
        <value>{pass}</value>
      </property>
      <ip_address>111.111.111.111</ip_address>
    </vrt_hst>
  </hosting>
  <plan-name>{plan}</plan-name>
</add>
```